# How to get all the values selected in a RadComboBox(multi-select drop-down) with check boxes on the server-side, asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I need to get all the values selected by user in multi-select(Check-Box) drop-down on the server side.

Comment: What you have tried so far. Put some effort in asking question.

Comment: I tried to get the selected values in a hidden literal in the code-behind. I believe it is working now. @shekar i had more text(code) in this which is not coming here when the question is getting posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var collection = comboBox.CheckedItems;

Where comboBox is the id of your RadCombobox